# EEG data processing: large data file seems empty

Tags: methodology, eeg, data

We have been running an experiment trying to collect ABR data using the Brainvision EP-PreAmp and Actichamp system. We ran several successful tests with short versions of our experiment, about 10-15 minutes of recording. We were able to process the data in eeglab and saw the components we were expecting.

We have recently been running our full experiment, recording for about 45-50 minutes. The files are necessarily much bigger. The test .eeg files were ~150mb and the full .eeg files are ~550mb. All of our Brainvision equipment seems to working (amps, batteries, electrodes), and we are able to get our impedances low before recording. However, when we import the vhdr files into eeglab, it looks like there's no data there. We are thinking this might be an eeglab problem - perhaps the file is too large and something's getting lost in the import?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the equipment, but can't you access the data from the ABR machine in another way? I have worked with similar equipment (visual recordings though) and that apparatus had the option to export as *.csv or other low-level data files. If that's possible you can open that with Matlab or other data analysis software.